# Swift Localizable String not working in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, localizable.strings

I don't know what's wrong with this. This is my `localizable string`

```
"sendEmailTo %s" = "We will send an email to %s. Thanks for watching";
```

and this is the way I'm using it into `Text()`

```
Text("sendEmailTo %s \("hello.world@apple.com")")
```

Do you have an idea of the error?, thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to replace `%s` with an email string, you need to get rid of it from the passed string to Text

```swift
Text("sendEmailTo \("hello.world@apple.com")")
```

Check out this blogpost [Localization in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/10/16/localization-in-swiftui/)